# Compositing pixelation (Hot Pixels)

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, color, blend-modes

I've noticed that when doing compositing in Blender that I end up with hot pixels that are sharp and distracting. The result in this case was using a color node to layer an emission render pass over an image to make a washed out pink grid back to the red it was in cycles. I do the same sort of color blending in Photoshop with much better results and no hot pixels. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening or how to better achieve the same effects in the compositor ? I would like to be able to use the awesome nodes like glare in blender to achieve a composited final image. Here are some screen shots to show the issue.

[image: Blender compositing node setup]

[image: Error seen in final comp vs. Photoshop comp]

Here is the result without color nodes or curves being used. Fixes hot pixels but comp is not really what I desire. Photoshop version looks right:
[image]

Comment: Screen, Overlay, and Colour blend modes are display referred and will break scene referred data. Also, curves are not behaving the way you probably think they are, so exposing that node would help diagnose. Those crap blend modes need to be gutted from Blender. Demonstrate the over without them as well.

Comment: It definitely reduced the hot pixels removing the blend modes but the result is not the comp I'm looking for. Seems that they really need to work on these nodes to make them useable.

Comment: It’s not the nodes, at least the ones that aren’t broken as opposed to the idiot algorithms from Photoshop, it’s where your knowledge is at likely. Scene referred workflows seem alien as hell at first, but once you grasp them there is no going back. Post where your comp starts at and post where you would like to take it. Ignore Photoshop and focus on specific image details. It’s easier to step through that way, and you’ll probably get a better grasp of the entire conceptual model by the end.